loop query to extract a pattern from a clob column
I have a clob column and I need to extract a pattern as rows. I am using a query like below which but returns a lot of duplicate rows. REGEXP_COUNT returns only 3 rows. Any reason and how to get unique rows?
    select REGEXP_SUBSTR(des, 'IS:</u><BR>(.*?)<BR><BR>', 1, LEVEL) as name
     from test 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(des,'IS:</u><BR>(.*?)<BR><BR>', 1);

Should return 5 unique rows but return lot of duplicate rows

why should i provide a mre and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example should you also read

This is a duplicate of How to convert comma separated values to rows in oracle? (yes, the regular expression here is more complicated than splitting a comma-delimited list but any of the regular expression-based solutions in the duplicate should also solve this problem - for example, the code here should be able to be directly inserted into this answer; just move the table name to the outer query and use DUAL in the hierarchical query fiddle).

If you have several rows in your table, the CONNECT BY condition you have written doesn't prevent to compare DES column from different rows... you need to add another condition like "PRIOR id = id"
